# Python Protocol with __getitem__ and typed keys

Tags: python, python-typing

I am looking for the correct type to annotate this code

```
def process_item(item: MyItemType) -> str:
    return f"Hello {item['name']} {item['age']} old"
```

i.e item is any object with `__getitem__()` and must have `name` and `age` keys.

```
import typing

class MyItemType(typing.Protocol):
    name: str
    age: int

    def __getitem__(self, key: ???)->???:
        ...
```

In practice it would mean valid inputs include
`pyspark.sql.Row` [instance](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Row.html), vanilla `dict` or custom object

```
class MyItem:
    def __init__(self, name:str, age: int):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __getitem__(self, k: ???) -> ???:
        if not hasattr(self, k):
            raise KeyError()
        return getattr(self, k)
```

I can do

```
class MyItemType[typing.TypedDict]:
    name: str
    age: int

def process_item(item: MyItemType):...
```

but since that is not a `typing.Protocol` this wouldn't work passing in the `pyspark.sql.Row` or custom class with these attributes.

Comment: Hmm now that I think about it `pyspark.sql.Row` doesnt have schema so a simple `class MyItemType(Protocol): def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> Any:` should do the job and handle missing keys in the `process_item()`

Comment: What you're showing as a type is something with name and age _attributes_, why not use e.g. `Mapping[str, Any]`

Comment: I don't think you can express this using Python's type system. the closest would be to use `Literal["name", "age"]` but it seems not quite right.

Comment: `Mapping[Literal["age", "name], Any]` would allow `f"Hello {item['name']} {item['age']} old"` but attempts to access other keys would be a type error.

Comment: hmm the more i think about it smells like bad design and doing `Mapping[str, Any]` is the only option if I want to support plain `dict`s. There is no way to check that particular dict instance has the keys during type checking (since the dict values can be `item = json.load(open('fp.json'))` and mypy has no idea of the contents.

Comment: @jonrsharpe right, although I guess this ends up working like a `TypedDict`, where any key access that is not a literal is rejected

Comment: So, some good reading here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/ Python decided to add a special case, but look at the sort of operations that are actually supported, in particular, "Operations with arbitrary str keys (instead of string literals or other expressions with known string values) should generally be rejected. This involves both destructive operations such as setting an item and read-only operations such as subscription expressions. "